# Lists in prolog won't print with comma

Tags: list, prolog

I have this code :

```
route(X,Y,[X|Y]) :-
    road(X,Y).

route(X,Y,[X|R]) :-
    road(X,Z),
    route(Z,Y,R).


road(arad,timisoara).
road(arad,sibiu).
road(arad,zerind).
road(zerind,oradea).
road(sibiu,fagaras).
road(sibiu,rimnicu_vilcea).
```

When I run it, it gives me :

```
?- route(arad, fagaras, P).

P = [arad,sibiu|fagaras] ? 

yes
```

it should be :

```
P = [arad,sibiu,fagaras] ?
```

with a comma after sibiu, not a bar.

Comment: You need to fix your base case: `route(X,Y,[X|Y]) :-
    road(X,Y).`  The `|` syntax denotes a *sublist*, so your `[X|Y]` is not the correct syntax for a list whose elements are just `X` and `Y`. It should be  `[X,Y]`. In short, if you want the comma, you have to use the comma. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first line, write `[X,Y]` instead of `[X|Y]` the later expects `Y` to be a list which isn't the case here.